# Local HTML File Scraping Urllib and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am very new to python and have been working from scratch on the following code for two weeks to scrape local files.  Probably nearly a hundred hours learning as much as I can about Python, versionality, importing packages such as lxml, bs4, requests, urllib, os, glob and more.

I'm hopelessly stuck on the first part on getting 12,000 HTML files with strange names all in one directory to load and parse with BeautifulSoup.  I want to get all this data into a csv file or just to output so I can copy it to a file using clipboard.

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

#THIS LOCAL FILE WORKS PERFECTLY. I HAVE 12,000 HTML FILES IN THIS DIRECTORY TO PROCESS.  HOW?
#my_url = 'file://127.0.0.1/C:\\My Web Sites\\BioFachURLS\\www.organic-bio.com\\en\\company\\1-SUNRISE-FARMS.html'
my_url = 'http://www.organic-bio.com/en/company/23694-MARTHOMI-ALLERGY-FREE-FOODS-GMBH'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

# grabs each field
contactname = page_soup.findAll("td", {"itemprop": "name"})
contactstreetaddress = page_soup.findAll("td", {"itemprop": "streetAddress"})
contactpostalcode = page_soup.findAll("td", {"itemprop": "postalCode"})
contactaddressregion = page_soup.findAll("td", {"itemprop": "addressRegion"})
contactaddresscountry = page_soup.findAll("td", {"itemprop": "addressCountry"})
contactfax = page_soup.findAll("td", {"itemprop": "faxNumber"})
contactemail = page_soup.findAll("td", {"itemprop": "email"})
contactphone = page_soup.findAll("td", {"itemprop": "telephone"})
contacturl = page_soup.findAll("a", {"itemprop": "url"})

#Outputs as text without tags
Company = contactname[0].text
Address = contactstreetaddress[0].text
Zip = contactpostalcode[0].text
Region = contactaddressregion[0].text
Country = contactaddresscountry[0].text
Fax = contactfax[0].text
Email = contactemail[0].text
Phone = contactphone[0].text
URL = contacturl[0].text

#Prints with comma delimiters

print(Company + ', ' + Address + ', ' + Zip + ', ' + Region + ', ' + Country + ', ' + Fax + ', ' + Email + ', ' + URL)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with running through folders with bunches of file before, so I could suggest a little help.

We will start with for loop to files from folder

```py
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as page_soup

phone = [] # A list to store all the phone
path = 'yourpath' # This is your folder name which stores all your html 
#be careful that you might need to put a full path such as C:\Users\Niche\Desktop\htmlfolder 
for filename in os.listdir(path): #Read files from your path

    #Here we are trying to find the full pathname
    for x in filename: #We will have A-H stored as path
        subpath = os.path.join(path, filename) 
        for filename in os.listdir(subpath):
        #Getting the full path of a particular html file
            fullpath = os.path.join(subpath, filename)
            #If we have html tag, then read it
            if fullpath.endswith('.html'): continue
            #Then we will run beautifulsoup to extract the contents
            soup = page_soup(open(fullpath), 'html.parser')
            #Then run your code
            # grabs each field
            contactname = page_soup.findAll("td", {"itemprop": "name"})
            contactstreetaddress = page_soup.findAll("td", {"itemprop": "streetAddress"})
            contactpostalcode = page_soup.findAll("td", {"itemprop": "postalCode"})
            contactaddressregion = page_soup.findAll("td", {"itemprop": "addressRegion"})
            contactaddresscountry = page_soup.findAll("td", {"itemprop": "addressCountry"})
            contactfax = page_soup.findAll("td", {"itemprop": "faxNumber"})
            contactemail = page_soup.findAll("td", {"itemprop": "email"})
            contactphone = page_soup.findAll("td", {"itemprop": "telephone"})
            contacturl = page_soup.findAll("a", {"itemprop": "url"})

            #Outputs as text without tags
            Company = contactname[0].text
            Address = contactstreetaddress[0].text
            Zip = contactpostalcode[0].text
            Region = contactaddressregion[0].text
            Country = contactaddresscountry[0].text
            Fax = contactfax[0].text
            Email = contactemail[0].text
            Phone = contactphone[0].text
            URL = contacturl[0].text
            #Here you might want to consider using dictionary or a list
            #For example append Phone to list call phone
            phone.append(Phone)
```

The code is a bit messy but it ran through all the possible folders (Even you have other folders inside your main folder) then try to find html tags, the open it.

I would suggest using dictionary with company as a key in which I presume that the company's name are different. A bunch of lists would also be great because your value will be sorted accordingly. I am not good with dictionary so I can't advise you more than this. I hope I answer your question.

P.S sorry for a messy code.

Edit : Fixing replace lxml with html.parser

Comment: Thank you so much.  I am now going to look at the code you sent.  I've been so frustrated by this problem, but was stubborn and didn't want to ask for help.  You are a saint.  Thank you so much!